# Why is there a Imaplib.abort EOF error after 10 correctly crawled messages?

Tags: python, outlook, imap

I need to Copy every mail from my 'inbox'+sub folders to 2 new folders, one for short subjects and another for the long ones. 
The crawl always abort after the 10th mail, and I need to repeat the process for 10 000 of them.. if someone had a solution I would be very grateful, here is my code :

```
import imaplib, getpass, re, email
pattern_uid = re.compile(b'\d+ \(UID (?P<uid>\d+)\)')

def parse_mailbox(data):
    flags, b, c = data.partition(' ')
    separator, b, name = c.partition(' ')
    return (flags, separator.replace('"', ''), name.replace('"', ''))

def connect(email):
    imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com",993)
    password = "*******" 
    imap.login(email, password)
    return imap

def disconnect(imap):
    imap.logout()

def parse_uid(data):
    match = pattern_uid.match(data)
    return match.group('uid')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    imap = connect('************')
    rv,data = imap.list()
    # print(data)
    if rv == 'OK':
        for mbox in data:
            flags,separator,name = parse_mailbox(bytes.decode(mbox))
            print(name)
            if 'HasNoChildren' in flags and '2' in name:
                name = name.replace('/ Inbox','Inbox')
                rv2, data2 = imap.select('"'+name+'"')
                print(rv2)
                resp, items = imap.search(None, 'All')
                email_ids  = items[0].split()
                # print(items)
                print(email_ids)
                 # Assuming that you are moving the latest email.
                # for mail in email_ids:
                #     if
                print(len(email_ids))
                for i in range(0,len(email_ids)):
                    print('NOUVEAU MESSAGE \n')
                    print(email_ids[i])
                    resp, data = imap.fetch(email_ids[i], "(UID)")
                    rv,sujet = imap.fetch(email_ids[i],("(RFC822)"))
                    varSubject= ""
                    for response_part in sujet:
                        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):

                            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response_part[1])
                            varSubject = msg['subject']
                            break
                    print(varSubject)
                    print(i)
                    print(type(data[0]))
                    print(data[0])
                    try : 
                        msg_uid = parse_uid(data[0])
                    except AttributeError:
                        continue
                    num = ""
                    dossier = ""
                    if  len(varSubject) <= 20:
                        dossier =  'INBOX/sujets_courts'
                        imap.create(dossier)
                    elif  len(varSubject) > 20:
                        dossier =  'INBOX/sujets_longs'
                        imap.create(dossier)
                    print(varSubject+'******'+dossier)
                    print(msg_uid)

                    result = imap.uid('COPY', msg_uid, dossier)

            # if result[0] == 'OK':
            #     mov, data = imap.uid('STORE', msg_uid , '+FLAGS', '(\Deleted)')
            #     imap.expunge()

    disconnect(imap)
```

The email and the password are substituted by '****'

Thanks a lot :)

console output :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lschaub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1011, in _command_complete
    typ, data = self._get_tagged_response(tag)
  File "C:\Users\lschaub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1131, in _get_tagged_response
    self._get_response()
  File "C:\Users\lschaub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1039, in _get_response
    resp = self._get_line()
  File "C:\Users\lschaub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1143, in _get_line
    raise self.abort('socket error: EOF')
imaplib.abort: socket error: EOF

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "movemail.py", line 44, in <module>
    resp, data = imap.fetch(email_ids[i], "(UID)")
  File "C:\Users\lschaub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 526, in fetch
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, message_set, message_parts)
  File "C:\Users\lschaub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1188, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Users\lschaub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1013, in _command_complete
    raise self.abort('command: %s => %s' % (name, val))
imaplib.abort: command: FETCH => socket error: EOF
```

Comment: Please provide the exception and stack trace.

Comment: done :) I edited it

Comment: The remote server closed the connection on you.  It shouldn't do that for an already existing folder.  To diagnose this you can turn on imaplib debugging, which should print out what it's sending and receiving.  See IMAP4.debug or imaplib.Debug.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured out that the problem comes from the creation of an already-created folder, but I could not find any `folder.exists()` look-a-like method in the imaplib doc...